Sas sort variables in order based on another table
I want to commit a clusterisation process on a dataset, however the issue is that some variables have only empty values. As the dataset has over 2k variables It is difficult to do remove them by hand so I created another dataset with numbers of missing values in each variable, transposed it, sorted ascending by value and transposed it back again. How do I order the first dataset by the same order of variables as second dataset so that I can remove first n number of variables that are empty?
I have macros such as DROPMISS however they only remove some of the missing variables so I feel like that is the only way to remove all variables with only missing values. Unless there is a way to cluster variables with such variables present.

The way to remove variables from a dataset is the DROP statement (or DROP= dataset option).  If you have a dataset with a list of variable names then you can use code generation to create the DROP statement.
The easiest way to perform code generation is to put the code you want into a macro variable and expand the macro variable at the point where you want that code to appear.
So if you have dataset name VARIABLES with two variables named NAME and NONMISSING then as long as the total length of the variable names you want to list is less than the limit for a single macro variable (64K bytes) then PROC SQL is the easiest way to put the list into a macro variable.
This code will put the names of all variables with NONMISSING=0 into the macro variable named VARLIST.
proc sql noprint;
  select nliteral(name) into :varlist separated by ' '
  from variables where nonmissing=0
  ;
quit;

You can now use that macro variable to generate your DROP statement.
data want;
  set have;
  drop &varlist ;
run;

Or a DROP= dataset option.
proc glm data=have(drop=&varlist);
  ...

